# find next word of a word from a string

Tags: java, string

I have written following code to get next word from a string in Java. I feel its very raw and I shouldn't have to write so much code for this but couldn't find any other way. Want to know if there are better ways available to do same:

```
public static String getNextWord(String str, String word) {
    String nextWord = null;
    // to remove multi spaces with single space
    str = str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    int totalLength = str.length();
    int wordStartIndex = str.indexOf(word);
    if (wordStartIndex != -1) {
        int startPos = wordStartIndex + word.length() + 1;
        if (startPos < totalLength) {
            int nextSpaceIndex = str.substring(startPos).indexOf(" ");
            int endPos = 0;
            if (nextSpaceIndex == -1) {
                // we've reached end of string, no more space left
                endPos = totalLength;
            } else {
                endPos = startPos + nextSpaceIndex;
            }
            nextWord = str.substring(startPos, endPos);
        }
    }
    return nextWord;
}
```

Note: the input word could be anything (multi words, single word, a word not in string etc).

Test:

```
    String text = "I am very happy with life";

    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, "I"));
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, "I am"));
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, "life"));
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, "with"));
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, "fdasfasf"));
    System.out.println(StringUtil.getNextWord(text, text));
```

Output:

```
am
very
null
life
null
null
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for regex. Something like this:

```
public static String getNextWord(String str, String word){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word+"\\W+(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);       
    return  m.find()? m.group(1):null;      
}
```

Comment: Fine. `Pattern.quote(word)` instead of word would safeguard against word containing (non-word) chars like period or question mark.

Comment: How will it compare performance wise if I need to run this quite a few times? Basically my full requirement is to find next 'right' word after given input word from the text. So I might have to keep getting next word until I find 'right' word.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will serve your purpose.

```
public static String getNextWord(String str, String word) {
    String[] words = str.split(" "), data = word.split(" ");
    int index = Arrays.asList(words).indexOf((data.length > 1) ? data[data.length - 1] : data[0]);
    return (index == -1) ? "Not Found" : ((index + 1) == words.length) ? "End" : words[index + 1];
}
```

Input (single word) :

```
String str = "Auto generated method stub";
String word = "method";
```

Out Put:

```
next word: stub
```

Input (multi-words) :

```
String str = "Auto generated method stub";
String word = "Auto generated";
```

Out Put:

```
next word: method
```

Input (missing word) :

```
String str = "Auto generated method stub";
String word = "was";
```

Out Put:

```
next word: Not Found
```

Input (end word) :

```
String str = "Auto generated method stub";
String word = "stub";
```

Out Put:

```
next word: End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of words by doing this:

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
```

This splits the string into strings when separated by a space. Note you keep needing to trim the str as you want to.
Now, you can somehow search in the array by finding some word and adding 1 to the index to get the next one.

```
nextword = words[words.indexOf(word) + 1];
```

Comment: actually I thought about this solution but it wouldn't work if input word is multi words.

Comment: then also split the multiwords and add the length to the index

Comment: @Carlos López Marí `words.indexOf(word) + 1` where `words` is an array not String. so you can call `indexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "I am very happy with life";
    System.out.println(getNextWord(text,"am"));
    System.out.println(getNextWord(text,"with"));
    System.out.println(getNextWord(text,"happy"));
    System.out.println(getNextWord(text,"I"));
    System.out.println(getNextWord(text,"life"));
}
public static String getNextWord(String text,String finditsNext){
    String result = "There is no next string";
    try {
        int findIndex = text.indexOf(finditsNext);
        String tep = text.substring(findIndex);
        if(tep.indexOf(" ") >0) {
        tep = tep.substring(tep.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        if(tep.indexOf(" ") >0)
            result = tep.substring(0, tep.indexOf(" "));
        else
            result = tep;
        }
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){

    }
    return result;
}
```

The output for the above is:

```
very
life
with
am
There is no next string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this solution works correctly:

```
public static String getNextWord(String str, String word) {
    String[] strArr = str.split(word);
    if(strArr.length > 1) {
        strArr = strArr[1].trim().split(" ");
        return strArr[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
public static String getNextWord(String str, String word) {
    try {
        List<String> text = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(word.split(" "));
        int index_of = text.indexOf(list.get(list.size() - 1));
        return (index_of == -1) ? null : text.get(index_of + 1);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```